# A* algorithm completes but returns suboptimal path

Tags: java, algorithm, a-star

The algorithm:

Uses a PQ that supports change priority operations.

Assume all the ADTs work correctly.

Example problem: Find the shortest path of operations to get from integer x to integer y using the following operations and weights; add/subtract 1 : 1, multiply/divide by 2 : 5, square : 10.

Tested against other types of graphs and inputs, sometimes it gets the shortest path, sometimes it gets a suboptimal, sometimes it times out.

```
import java.util.*;



/**
 * Represents a graph of vertices.
 */
public interface AStarGraph<Vertex> {

    List<WeightedEdge<Vertex>> neighbors(Vertex v);

    double estimatedDistanceToGoal(Vertex s, Vertex goal);

}

public interface ShortestPathsSolver<Vertex> {
    SolverOutcome outcome();
    List<Vertex> solution();
    double solutionWeight();
    int numStatesExplored();
    double explorationTime();
}

public interface ExtrinsicMinPQ<T> {
    /* Inserts an item with the given priority value. */
    void add(T item, double priority);
    /* Returns true if the PQ contains the given item. */
    boolean contains(T item);
    /* Returns the minimum item. */
    T getSmallest();
    /* Removes and returns the minimum item. */
    T removeSmallest();
    /* Changes the priority of the given item. Behavior undefined if the item doesn't exist. */
    void changePriority(T item, double priority);
    /* Returns the number of itemToPriority in the PQ. */
    int size();
}

public enum SolverOutcome {
    SOLVED, TIMEOUT, UNSOLVABLE
}


public class ArrayHeapMinPQ<T> implements ExtrinsicMinPQ<T> {
    private ArrayList<PriorityNode> heap;
    int count;
    private HashMap<T, PriorityNode> items;

    public ArrayHeapMinPQ() {
        heap = new ArrayList<>();
        heap.add(0, new PriorityNode(null, Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY));
        count = 0;  // For convenient math
        items = new HashMap<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void add(T item, double priority) {
        if(contains(item)){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        PriorityNode pn = new PriorityNode(item, priority);
        if(count == 0){
            heap.add(1, pn);
            count++;
        }else{
            heap.add(count+1, pn);
            swim(count+1);
            count++;

        }
        items.put(item, pn);

    }

    private void swap(int i, int j){
        Collections.swap(heap, i, j);
    }
    private void swim(int i){
        while(i > 1){
            PriorityNode cur = heap.get(i);
            if((cur.compareTo(heap.get(i/2)) >= 0)){
                break;
            }
            swap(i, i/2);
            i = i/2;
        }

    }

    private void sink(int k){
        while (2*k <= size()-1) {
            if(2*k+1 <= size()-1) {
                if (heap.get(2 * k).compareTo(heap.get(2 * k + 1)) < 0) {
                    if (heap.get(k).compareTo(heap.get(2 * k)) > 0) {
                        swap(k, 2 * k);
                        k = 2 * k;
                        continue;
                    }
                } else if(heap.get(k).compareTo(heap.get(2*k+1)) > 0){
                    swap(2*k+1, k);
                    k = 2*k +1;
                    continue;}
            }
            else if (heap.get(k).compareTo(heap.get(2 * k)) > 0) {
                swap(k, 2 * k);
                k = 2 * k;
                continue;}
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int size(){
        return heap.size();
    }

    public PriorityNode getRoot(){
        return heap.get(1);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(T item) {
        return items.containsKey(item);}

    @Override
    public T getSmallest() {
        if(heap.size() == 0){
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        return getRoot().getItem();
    }

    @Override
    public T removeSmallest() {
        if(heap.size() == 1){
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        T item = heap.get(1).item;
        swap(1, size()-1);
        heap.remove(size()-1);
        if(size() > 1){
            sink(1);
        }
        items.remove(item);
        count--;
        return item;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return heap.size() == 1;
    }


    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public void changePriority(T T, double priority) {
        if(heap.size() == 0){
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        PriorityNode tochange = items.get(T);
        double prioritysearch = tochange.getPriority();
        double currprior = getRoot().getPriority();
        int left = 0;
        int right = 0;
        if((prioritysearch != currprior)){
            if (currprior > prioritysearch){
                add(T, priority);
                return;
            }
            left = heapTraverse(prioritysearch, tochange, 2);
            right = heapTraverse(prioritysearch, tochange, 3);

        }
        if(left == -1 && right == -1){
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        else if(left > 0){
            PriorityNode toChange = heap.get(left);
            toChange.setPriority(priority);
            if(priority < heap.get(left/2).getPriority()){
                swim(left);
            }else
                sink(left);
        }

        else {
            PriorityNode toChange = heap.get(right);
            toChange.setPriority(priority);
            if (priority < heap.get(right / 2).getPriority()) {
                swim(right);
            } else
                sink(right);
        }
    }

    private int heapTraverse(double priority, PriorityNode node, int index){
        if(index > heap.size()-1){
            return -1;
        }
        PriorityNode curr = heap.get(index);
        double currprior = curr.getPriority();
        if(currprior == priority && node.equals(curr)){
            return index;
        } else if(currprior > priority){
            return -1;
        }else{
            if(heapTraverse(priority, node, index*2) == -1){

                return heapTraverse(priority, node, index*2 +1);}

            else {return heapTraverse(priority, node, index*2);}

        }
    }

    private class PriorityNode implements Comparable<PriorityNode> {
        private T item;
        private double priority;

        PriorityNode(T e, double p) {
            this.item = e;
            this.priority = p;
        }

        T getItem() {
            return item;
        }

        double getPriority() {
            return priority;
        }

        void setPriority(double priority) {
            this.priority = priority;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(PriorityNode other) {
            if (other == null) {
                return -1;
            }
            return Double.compare(this.getPriority(), other.getPriority());
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if( o == null) {
                throw new NullPointerException();
            }
            if (o.getClass() != this.getClass()) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return ((PriorityNode) o).getItem().equals(getItem());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return item.hashCode();
        }
    }

public class WeightedEdge<Vertex> {
    private Vertex v;
    private Vertex w;
    private double weight;

    public WeightedEdge(Vertex v, Vertex w, double weight) {
        this.v = v;
        this.w = w;
        this.weight = weight;
    }
    public Vertex from() {
        return v;
    }
    public Vertex to() {
        return w;
    }
    public double weight() {
        return weight;
    }
}

public class SolutionPrinter {
    /** Summarizes the result of the search made by this solver without actually
     *  printing the solution itself (if any).
     */
    public static <Vertex> void summarizeOutcome(ShortestPathsSolver<Vertex> solver) {
        summarizeSolution(solver, "", false);
    }

/** Summarizes the result of the search made by this solver and also
 *  prints each vertex of the solution, connected by the given delimiter,
 *  e.g. delimiter = "," would return all states separated by commas.
 */
public static <Vertex> void summarizeSolution(ShortestPathsSolver<Vertex> solver,
                                              String delimiter) {
    summarizeSolution(solver, delimiter, true);
}

private static <Vertex> String solutionString(ShortestPathsSolver<Vertex> solver,
                                              String delimiter) {
    List<String> solutionVertices = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Vertex v : solver.solution()) {
        solutionVertices.add(v.toString());
    }
    return String.join(delimiter, solutionVertices);
}

private static <Vertex> void summarizeSolution(ShortestPathsSolver<Vertex> solver,
                                               String delimiter, boolean printSolution) {

    System.out.println("Total states explored in " + solver.explorationTime()
            + "s: " + solver.numStatesExplored());

    if (solver.outcome() == SolverOutcome.SOLVED) {
        List<Vertex> solution = solver.solution();
        System.out.println("Search was successful.");
        System.out.println("Solution was of length " + solution.size()
                + ", and had total weight " + solver.solutionWeight() + ":");
        if (printSolution) {
            System.out.println(solutionString(solver, delimiter));
        }
    } else if (solver.outcome() == SolverOutcome.TIMEOUT) {
        System.out.println("Search timed out, considered " + solver.numStatesExplored()
                + " vertices before timing out.");
    } else { // (solver.outcome() == SolverOutcome.UNSOLVABLE)
        System.out.println("Search determined that the goal is unreachable from source.");
    }
}
```

}

public class AStarSolver implements ShortestPathsSolver {

```
private final AStarGraph<Vertex> graph;
private Vertex source;
private Vertex dest;
private SolverOutcome result;
private HashMap<Vertex, Double> distTo = new HashMap<>();
private ArrayHeapMinPQ<Vertex> fringe = new ArrayHeapMinPQ<>();
private HashMap<Vertex, WeightedEdge<Vertex>> edgeTo = new HashMap<>(); // answers the question which vertex to ge to this vertex
private double solutionweight;
private List<Vertex> solution;
private ArrayList<Vertex> marked = new ArrayList<>();
private double timetosolve;
private int numofstates = 0;


public AStarSolver(AStarGraph<Vertex> input, Vertex start, Vertex end, double timeout ){

    graph = input;
    source = start;
    dest = end;
    if(start.equals(end)){
        solutionweight = 0;
        solution = List.of(start);
        result = SolverOutcome.SOLVED;
        numofstates = 0;
        timetosolve = 0;
        return;
    }
    fringe.add(start, 0.0);
    distTo.put(start, 0.0);
    while (!fringe.isEmpty()) {
        Vertex src = fringe.removeSmallest();
        numofstates++;
        marked.add(src);

        List<WeightedEdge<Vertex>> neighbors = graph.neighbors(src);
        for(WeightedEdge<Vertex> e: neighbors){

            double heur = graph.estimatedDistanceToGoal(e.to(), dest);
            if ((heur == Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY || marked.contains(e.to())) && !e.to().equals(dest)) {
                continue;
            }
            double distFr = distTo.get(e.from()) + e.weight();

            if(!distTo.containsKey(e.to())){
                distTo.put(e.to(), distFr);
            }
            if (!fringe.contains(e.to())) {
                fringe.add(e.to(),  distFr + heur);
                edgeTo.put(e.to(), e);
            }

            if (distTo.get(e.to()) > distFr) {
                fringe.changePriority(e.to(), heur + distFr);
                edgeTo.put(e.to(), e);
                distTo.put(e.to(), distFr);
            }
            if (e.to().equals(dest)) {
                solutionweight = distTo.get(e.to());
                solution = pathTracer(e);
                timetosolve = sw.elapsedTime();
                result = SolverOutcome.SOLVED;
                return;
            }

            if (e.to().equals(dest)) {
                solutionweight = distTo.get(e.to());
                solution = pathTracer(e);
                timetosolve = sw.elapsedTime();
                result = SolverOutcome.SOLVED;
                return;
            }


        }
        if (timeout < sw.elapsedTime()){
            result = SolverOutcome.TIMEOUT;
            return;
        }
    }
    result = SolverOutcome.UNSOLVABLE;
    solution = List.of();

}

private List<Vertex> pathTracer(WeightedEdge<Vertex> e) {
    ArrayList<Vertex> path = new ArrayList<>();
    path.add(e.to());
    path.add(e.from());
    while (!e.from().equals(source)) {
        e = edgeTo.get(e.from());
        path.add(e.from());
    }
    Collections.reverse(path);
    return path;
}

@Override
public SolverOutcome outcome() {
    return result;
}

@Override
public List solution() {
    return solution;
}

@Override
public double solutionWeight() {
    return solutionweight;
}

@Override
public int numStatesExplored() {
    return numofstates;
}

@Override
public double explorationTime() {
    return timetosolve;
}

public class IntegerHopGraph implements AStarGraph<Integer> {

    @Override
    public List<WeightedEdge<Integer>> neighbors(Integer v) {
        ArrayList<WeightedEdge<Integer>> neighbors = new ArrayList<>();
        neighbors.add(new WeightedEdge<>(v, v * v, 10));
        neighbors.add(new WeightedEdge<>(v, v * 2, 5));
        neighbors.add(new WeightedEdge<>(v, v / 2, 5));
        neighbors.add(new WeightedEdge<>(v, v - 1, 1));
        neighbors.add(new WeightedEdge<>(v, v + 1, 1));
        return neighbors;
    }

    @Override
    public double estimatedDistanceToGoal(Integer s, Integer goal) {
        // possibly fun challenge: Try to find an admissible heuristic that
        // speeds up your search. This is tough!
        return 0;
    }
}



public class DemoIntegerHopPuzzleSolution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int start = 17;
        int goal = 111;

        IntegerHopGraph ahg = new IntegerHopGraph();

        ShortestPathsSolver<Integer> solver = new AStarSolver<>(ahg, start, goal, 10);
        SolutionPrinter.summarizeSolution(solver, " => ");

    }
}
```

}

To get from x = 11, to y = 117 the algorithm gives this result:

Total states explored in 0.019s: 110

Search was successful.

Solution was of length 7, and had total weight 19.0:

17 => 16 => 15 => 225 => 224 => 223 => 111

The correct result should is:

Total states explored in 0.018s: 338 <--- may vary.

Search was successful.

Solution was of length 6, and had total weight 18.0:

17 => 16 => 15 => 225 => 112 => 111

Comment: Please post a minimal, compileable, self-contained example program so that we can run it ourselves; see http://sscce.org/

Comment: This would involve uploading several packages and hundreds of lines of code. I'm not sure how to go about that efficiently.

Comment: Copy your current code into a new project, then remove everything that is not related to this problem.

Comment: Just as an example, the `Stopwatch` is unrelated to your problem. It should not be in the code you posted here.

Comment: In the end, it should be enough to post the `Vertex`, `WeightedEdge`, `AStarGraph` and a few others. And please include a `main` method.

Comment: I believe I added all the necessary interfaces and classes now. Obviously needed to be separated out. I don't know if SO has a way to upload classes and interfaces separately.

Comment: This might be somewhat trivial - but Astar search only works well if the heuristic never overestimates the cost. Have you verified that?

Comment: I can only emphasize on the comment from @Hans Olsson. An A*, functional on other graphs, which gives suboptimal paths on a particular model ... that definitely points towards a heuristic that sometimes overestimates the remaining cost. A very simple way to check this is to set the heuristic to 0 for any input, and to see if the paths returned are still suboptimal.

Comment: Take a minimal failing example and debug it.

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys but I figured it out. My algorithm terminates prematurely. It stops when it sees the finish, not when it is on the top of the heap like it should.

Comment: @user9778630 A* should terminate as soon as it reaches the destination, not when the heap is empty. So even if it now returns correct results, I'd advice you to look deeper into it, so you can be sure that what you implemented is indeed the A* algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help guys but I figured it out. My algorithm terminates prematurely. It stops when it sees the finish, not when it is on the top of the heap like it should.